# Is this question even solvable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve $x^{x^{3/2}} = 3x/2$.  My teacher said that it's a closed equation and could not be solved.  Then I plotted this equation on Wolfram Alpha and the graph showed 2 solutions.  I tried it by solving it by logarithm but it became very complex.  Then I tried solving it by inequalities and the solution set was coming greater than 1, but on Wolfram Alpha the solutions are about 0.52 and 1.57.

Is it even solvable?

Comment: $x^{x^{1.5}}=1.5$ has a nice solution.

Comment: If Wolfram does not give exact solutions then it is unlikely 'solvable' although one cannot solely rely on the website.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be solvable by elementary methods?  There are such things as "transcendental equations" and "non-elementary functions" that you might want to read a little bit about.  Even trying to solve $x=a^x$ leaves the realm of the elementary functions.  At best, you might find that your function falls into a special case where the solution can be found by inspection (like solving $x^x = 4$ works for $x=2$).  Otherwise there might be a specially named function to solve your problem (*like the lambert-w function*).  If not, then you might have to be satisfied with approximations

Comment: I cannot prove it, but I am $99.\overline{9}\%$ sure it cannot be solvable in terms of elementary functions. Also, please note the difference between "analitically solvable" and "numerically solvable"

Comment: *Mathematica* gives the numerical solutions as $0.521709$ and $1.54859$.

Comment: "*$x^{x^{1.5}} = 1.5$ has a nice solution*" @MichaelRozenberg does it?  Is that sarcasm?  They don't look very pretty to me.  [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex%5E1.5+%3D+1.5) is giving the solutions in terms of lambert-W functions (as I would have expected)

Comment: @JMoravitz $\sqrt[3]{\frac{9}{4}}$ is a root. Human is still a bit of better than computer!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Or more elegantly, $(3/2)^{2/3}$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: You deserve a medal for this observation :D. It is very interesting to see Wolfram fail.

Comment: You very probably found this by inspection though, yes?  Not through some analytical means @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, og course. Easy to see that it's a root and easy to prove that we have no another roots.

Comment: When the exponent is close to 1, say $1+y$, the solutions are close to $x=1\pm\sqrt y$

Comment: To generalize @MichaelRozenberg's example, if $x^a = a$, then you can raise the  power tower as high as you want. If $a = m/n$ is rational, then $x= \sqrt[m]{{\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)}^n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you graphed the function
$$f(x)=x^{x^{3/2}}-\frac{3 }{2}x$$ you noticed that it goes through a minimum "around" $x=1$ (which is a very nice value !).

Using Taylor series around $x=1$, we have
$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)+\frac{3}{2} (x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$ Neglecting the higher order terms and solving the quadratic equation in $(x-1)$ gives as *estimates* of the roots
$$x_1=\frac{7-\sqrt{13}}{6}\approx 0.565741\qquad \text{and} \qquad x_2=\frac{7+\sqrt{13}}{6}\approx 1.76759$$ Using these estimates as starting points for Newton method, we should get the dollowing iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.5657414541 \\
 1 & 0.5205808928 \\
 2 & 0.5217078869
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.767591879 \\
 1 & 1.620506201 \\
 2 & 1.558309746 \\
 3 & 1.548791358 \\
 4 & 1.548591418 \\
 5 & 1.548591331
\end{array}
\right)$$ which are the solutions for ten significant figures.

For sure, these are the same as those given in Rhys Hughes's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not solvable exactly, but the solution can be approximated via iteration.

We find $g : f(x)=0\iff g(x)=x$, then $$f(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n)=0 \text{ where }x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$$

So we have: $x^{x\sqrt x}=\frac{3x}{2}\to x=\frac23x^{x\sqrt x} \ [1] \text{ and } x=\log_x^{\frac23}(\frac{3x}{2}) \ [2]$

Starting with $x_0=1$ for $[1]$ and $x_0=2$ for $[2]$ we get that

$$[1] \to 0.5217085869$$
$$[2]\to 1.548591331$$
 both to calculator accuracy.